# Create invert area chart with amCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, area-chart

With amCharts, I'm struggling on creating this chart where Red series is bounded to the top and Blue series is bounded to the bottom.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thank you

[image]